# PostgreSQL Transaction with id 15 inserted before id 16

Tags: postgresql

I have this case, example i have table invoice then process 2 transaction almost at same time :

```
1. 12:55:11.21212 got id from postgresql 15
2. 12:55:11.24441 got id from postgresql 16
```

but transaction inserted on table 16 is first inserted then id 15 after that, like this

```
id         time          trx
14   12:55:11.11231       A
16   12:55:11.24441       B
```

then after refresh the table, id with 15 like delay:

```
id         time           user
14    12:55:11.11231       A
15    12:55:11.21212       A
16    12:55:11.24441       A
```

why this happen ?

Comment: How is the `time` value generated?

Comment: generate by now()

Comment: `now()` returns the time at the start of the transaction, not the time when the row was inserted. It seems like you want `clock_timestamp()` instead

Comment: if i change to clock_timestamps() the id will normally inserted ? i mean will be 15 then 16 ?

Comment: No, it will simply use the actual time when the row was inserted. It won't change the ID

Comment: because i need the concurrency to update the row, i will do update to calculate value sum() where id < id (last inserted every new row was inserted) if the id lowe not yet inserted the value is missing on sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is perfectly normal.

First, if you get the timestamp as `current_timestamp` or the non-standard `now()`, that is the timestamp when the database transaction started.

If you use `clock_timestamp()`, which returns the wall clock timestamp, and you auto-generate the primary key with a sequence (`serial` or `bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`), that would make the window for the race condition much smaller. But it could still happen that a process loses the CPU between the time when it retrieves the timestamp and when it generates the sequence value, so that the timestamp of two rows ends up with a different ordering than the primary key.

I recommend that you use either the primary key or the timestamp to define the ordering. The primary key has the advantage of being unique.